# Почему не записываются данные в файл?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Это середина кода. Из файла берётся id пользователя, через апи берётся список его групп. В текстовом файле 2 пользователя. У одного группы закрыты, у другого нет. Алгоритм должен записать в файл группы "открытого юзера", но он этого не делает потому что есть закрытый юзер. если этого юзера удалить из файла, то всё работает. Сделал проверку на ошибку и всё равно не записывает. Притом что закрытый юзер стоит последним в списке.

```
$lines = file('frend_list.txt');
$fsave = fopen("save.txt","w");

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

        $query=file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?user_id=".$line."&extended=1&access_token=".$token);
        $data=json_decode($query);
        if (!isset ($data->error)) {
        $count=$data->response[0];
        $result = array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $result[] = 'http://vk.com/club'.$data->response[$i]->gid."\r\n";
        }

        fwrite($fsave,implode(' ',$result));        
        fclose($fsave);
        }
    else {
    echo 'Ошибка, пользователь скрыл группы!';}
    }
```

Comment: Раз используете `file_get_contents`, то разумно будет использовать  для записи в файл `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, дело вот в этом

> file()
> Возвращает файл в виде массива. Каждый
> элемент массива соответствует строке
> файла, **с символами новой строки
> включительно.**

в запрос попадает что-то типа 215125**\r\n**, в результате чего апи отказывается искать такого пользователя. Для получения чистого айдишника достаточно сделать $id = intval($line), но в целом такой метод сохранения данных вызывает ожидание ошибки.

Заодно сразу скажу, что файл у вас открывается вне цикла, а закрывается в цикле, поэтому второй же валидный пользователь обрушит вам весь скрипт.